# PHP cron job include absolute file path

Tags: php, include, cron

I'm running a cron job configurated in CPanel:

```
**cd /home/DOMAIN_A/public_html/ ; php host_cron_job.php**
```

In the host_cron_job.php file I am trying to access with the absolute file path other file in the same server but it's other domain, something like:

```
**include "/home/DOMAIN_B/public_html/config.php";**
```

But I get this error:

```
**<b>Warning</b>:  include(/home/DOMAIN_B/public_html/config.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>/home/DOMAIN_A/public_html/host_cron_job.php</b>**
```

Anyone having solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UNIX user running the Cron task does not have the authorisation to access `/home/DOMAIN_B/public_html/config.php`. Log-in as this user, and try to access this path step-by-step. Adjust permissions as required using the `chmod` command.

The user must be able to "eXecute" the following directories (which means "enter those directories" for UNIX permissions) :

- /
- /home
- /home/DOMAIN_B
- /home/DOMAIN_B/public_html

And it must have a Read permission on both `/home/DOMAIN_B/public_html/config.php` and `/home/DOMAIN_B/public_html/config.php` :

Basically, your task should be :

```
* * * * * php /home/DOMAIN_A/public_html/host_cron_job.php
```

or

```
* * * * * cd /home/DOMAIN_A/public_html && php host_cron_job.php
```

depending on your environment needs, and with the scheduling parameters of your choice.

**Note :** I'd rather use `&&` than ';', this will avoid the execution of the PHP script if going to the directory fails at first.

Comment: Your sample cron line is probably incorrect. If OP is doing a cd into the script's directory, it's probably for a reason. If the script isn't written with absolute paths, it'll now be running in the WRONG working directory and any relative includes/requires will be broken.

Comment: Considering the fact that he uses absolute paths, I ruled out this possiblity. Still, I'll add a version using the `cd` pre-requisite.